# Copiar un objeto de un vector

Tags: java

--

Hola.

Quiero copiar un objeto de un vector a la última posición del mismo, ya lo logre, pero quisiera saber si este es el método correcto o si java.util.vector tiene algún método especializado para copiarlos en una posición dada.

```java
Computador computador1;
Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
int posicionCopiar = leer.nextInt();
computador1 = (Computador)computadores.elementAt(posicionCopiar);
computadores.add(computador1);
```

Gracias.

Comment: Te sugiero que pongas el código completo en donde podamos ver elementAt y de donde sacas computadores?

Comment: elementAt es un metodo de java.util.vector https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#add(E)

Comment: Listo ya lo tienes.